Illegal Hardware Instruction
Currently, I'm working with Jetson Nano 2Gb, and I facing the problem about assembly when I debug with gdb, I receive
92      __asm__ __volatile__("mrs %[res], daif": [res] "=r" (res)::);
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
INTERRUPTS_ENABLED () at Sx1278.cpp:92

And this is assembly code that causing that bug
__inline__ int INTERRUPTS_ENABLED(void) {
    int res;
    __asm__ __volatile__("mrs %[res], daif": [res] "=r" (res)::);
    return ((res >> 7) & 1) == 0;
}

__inline__ void ENABLE_INTERRUPTS(void) {
    if (!INTERRUPTS_ENABLED()) {
        __asm__ __volatile__("msr daifset, #2");
    }
}

__inline__ void DISABLE_INTERRUPTS(void) {
    if (INTERRUPTS_ENABLED()) {
        __asm__ __volatile__("msr daifclr, #2");
    }
}

I have no experience with this problem.
I use this repo to control gpio pin
https://github.com/Rubberazer/JETGPIO
Some information about my project:
I need to communicate between module Sx1278 (LoRa) and Jetson Nano board.
This is my github for Jetson Nano and module LoRa Ra-02:
github
It's include Makefile. I just modify some function based on this repo
To running this program, I only use makefile, that generate executable file. I thought it's caused by toolchain, but I can't fix it.
Some information: When I use OS raspbian 32 bit it run normally. But when I use OS 64 bit, it's facing that problem, and my module run on Aarch64 architecture. Jetson Nano don't just have os version 64 bit.
Has anyone experienced a similar problem when using the JETGPIO library on a 64-bit Jetson Nano or another Aarch64 system? Any suggestions on how to diagnose and fix this issue would be immensely helpful.

Some queries : (a) Can you provide a link to the source file Sx1278.cpp in which the illegal exception occurs, at it doesn't seem to be part of the JETGPIO library mentioned in the question. (b) Are you trying to run the program as bare-metal or a Linux user space application? The INTERRUPTS_ENABLED C function with inline assembly is trying to modify the DAIF register which contains Interrupt Mask Bits which as a guess a Linux user space application won't have permission to do. (c) Was the Sx1278.cpp source file intended to run on a Jetson Nano, or is it being ported from another board?

Hi sir,
(1). This is my link to source file link (2). According to the JETGPIO library, I think it's running on bare metal. (3). The file Sx1278.cpp is used to read and write registers to a LoRa module named Sx1278, not just for running on Jetson.

What CPU does that board have?  Is mrs a privileged instruction, if this is in user-space?

My board running on Cortex-A57 CPU cores.Sorry, but I don't understand your mean user-space

@PeterCordes According to Jetson Nano the CPU is a Quad-core ARM Cortex-A57 MPCore processor. ARM Cortex-A57 MPCore Processor Technical Reference Manual r1p3 says implements the AArch64 architecture. I haven't yet checked the AArch64 documentation to confirm which instructions are privileged.

@DominicNg Can you explain how your are running your program? E.g. is it after Linux has booted on the Jetson Nano Cortex-A57 CPU cores?

@ChesterGillon I've written a Makefile. After that, it's generate an executable file and I just run sudo ./myprogram. I was think that bug caused by toolchain. This is my makefile Makefile

I can't migrate this to SE, but I think it would probably be better served there.

For anyone interested, this is now on SE at Illegal Hardware Instruction in JetSon Nano

thanks for your support !!!
